# How can I align multiple lists in the same row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What happens:

[image]

What I want to happen:

[image]

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler1(this);" value="Front flip variaion (ramp)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler2(this);" value="Front flip variaion (flat)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler3(this);" value="Backflip variations" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler4(this);" value="Sideflip Variations (ramp)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler5(this);" value="Twists and other tricks"/>

<div1 class="inner" style="display:none;">
<ul>
    <li><a>Front full</a></a>
    <li><a>Double Front</a>
    <li><a>Aerial twist</a>
</ul>
</div1>

<div2 class="inner" style="display:none;">
<ul>
    <li><a>front 180</a>
    <li><a class="click" onclick="tr4(this); hide(this)">Webster</a>
    <li><a class="click" onclick="tr4(this); hide(this)">Loser</a>
</ul>
</div2>

<div3 class="inner" style="display:none;">
<ul>
    <li><a>Off-axis backtuck</a>
    <li><a>Back Full</a>
</ul>
</div3>
```

CSS:

```
div1 {
    color:blue;
}
div2 {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left:150px;
    }
div3 {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left: 300px;
}
```

JS:

```
function showSpoiler1(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div1")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler2(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div2")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler3(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div3")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
```

I want all the lists to horizontally line up with each other. When i use absolute positioning the text in the next section of my file doesnt move down so my lists collide with it. How could I make them line up and keep them from intersecting with th heading under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `table` for each div. This should work as you want.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div1 class="inner" style="display:none;">
            ...
         </div1>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div2 class="inner" style="display:none;">
           ...
         </div2>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why didn't I think of this! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling to display: inline-block or float them to the left;